# using facexlib, Low Quality Faces (blurry) after detecting and warpalign faces using Facexlib

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I am using Facexlib library to detect, crop (warpalign) and resize (512x512) the faces from photographic images (high resolutions 4K or above). In some cases, the output images are low quality even though faces is bigger in size more than 1Kx1K resolutions. Here is code in Facexlib library for detecting and warpalign the faces:

```
self.face_helper.read_image(img)
# get face landmarks for each face
self.face_helper.get_face_landmarks_5(only_center_face=only_center_face, eye_dist_threshold=5)
# eye_dist_threshold=5: skip faces whose eye distance is smaller than 5 pixels
# align and warp each face
self.face_helper.align_warp_face()
```

here is link for these function: [Face Detection using Facexlib](https://github.com/xinntao/facexlib/blob/master/facexlib/utils/face_restoration_helper.py#L234C14-L234C14)

Below is Detected Image. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNNky.png)

[Original Image is here](https://snapshots-ml-public.s3.amazonaws.com/081A3581.png) (can not upload here as size is bigger)

How can I detect and crop (warp and align) faces from high resolution images ? I tried different interpolation method, but there is no difference in image quality. I tried following interpolation methods:
cv2.INTER_NEAREST
cv2.INTER_LINEAR
cv2.INTER_AREA
cv2.INTER_CUBIC
cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4

I tried multiple interpolation techniques in warpalign method as flags, but no difference in image quality.

Comment: On my mobile phone I cant directly see the blur in your "Detected Image" link. Can you explain where it is seen best in the image?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/using-facexlib-low-quality-faces-blurry-after-detecting-and-cv2-warpalign-faces-using-facexlib/13850

Comment: OP probably means the image has a lower resolution than the source. looks normalized to a fixed size, 512 by 512.